# Join tables, count based on value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table alpha:

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
```

Table beta:

```
ID | state
----------
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 2
2  | 1
```

I would like to get a result like the following:

```
ID | Count(state=1) | Count (state=2)
-------------------------------------
1  | 1              | 2
2  | 1              | 0
3  | 0              | 0
```

How do I do this with SQL?
I can get the table without the result of ID 3, but that is not what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS State1Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN b.state = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS State2Count
    FROM alpha a
        LEFT JOIN beta b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
    GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. The keyword LEFT is the answer!